# Statsd messages not showing up in Graphite dashboard

Tags: stats, graphite

Ubuntu 11.10

Everything worked when I first setup statsd and graphite.  Once I rebooted, it no longer works, which makes me think something about graphite or carbon needs to be started.

Now that I've rebooted, I go to a terminal and type

```
node stats.js dConfig.js
```

And statsd sayd "server is up".  I have dumpMessages = true, so I see all of the messages hitting the statsd server.

Graphite is on the same machine so dConfig.js has 127.0.0.1. dConfig.js also has port 2003 for graphite.  I don't think I changed the port from 2003, but where do I find that?

The problem is, I cannot see any of the stats in the graphite console.  I can nav to http:/127.0.0.1/ and see the graphite console.  I even see old counters and timers.  But I do not see any new data in the graph.

An example msg to statsd is:

slolife.TimingTest:198|ms

So in graphite, I look for slolife / TimingTests, but cannot find that stat/folder.

What do I need to start or check to get the data to show in Graphite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out carbon was not running.  When i would run this command:

```
sudo /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start
```

It would return:

```
Pidfile /opt/graphite/storage/carbon-cache-a.pid already exists, is carbon-cache already running?
```

I figured it was running.  But I tried running example-client.py, and it said it couldn't connect to port 2003.